# Can't find required permission to create S3 Batch job in IAM

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I am attempting to create an S3 Batch (not AWS Batch, this is S3 Batch) job via boto3, and cannot figure out what permissions I need to enable for successful creation. I keep getting an "Access Denied" when I try to create the job, but it works fine when I apply the S3 Full Access policy to the execution role. Not a good long-term solution, obviously...

I am pretty certain that I need to add a specific permission in IAM, but I can't figure out which one. I can't see a "CreateJob" permission anywhere. Possibly I need to add access to some kind of s3 control bucket where the job is written?

I have tried adding permissions to a couple variations of what could be the S3 control bucket, but I haven't been successful yet.

This works fine when full S3 perms policy is applied:

```
import boto3

s3_control_client = boto3.client('s3control', region_name='us-east-1')
response = s3_control_client.create_job([very long and boring])
```

This is the output (scrubbed) that I get in the logs when I try to run with what I think are acceptable permissions.

```
2019-05-23 18:35:37,934 Starting new HTTPS connection (1): [ACCOUNTIDNUMBER].s3-control.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443
2019-05-23 18:35:38,040 https://[ACCOUNTIDNUMBER].s3-control.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 "POST /v20180820/jobs HTTP/1.1" 403 204
2019-05-23 18:35:38,040 Response headers: {'x-amz-id-2': '[SCRUBBED]', 'x-amz-request-id': '[SCRUBBED], [SCRUBBED]', 'Date': 'Thu, 23 May 2019 18:35:38 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/xml', 'Content-Length': '204', 'Server': 'AmazonS3'}
2019-05-23 18:35:38,041 Response body:
b'<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>[SCRUBBED]</RequestId>
```

Any ideas on what permissions I need to enable here for this to complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/batch-ops-iam-role-policies.html#batch-ops-job-required-permissions), you need `s3:CreateJob`, as well as `iam:PassRole` to the role that will be attached to the batch job.

So, something likes this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/ROLE_NAME"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateJob"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no special S3 batch job permissions that you can use. There might be some variations of permissions that you need depending on your use case. In general, you will need these permissions.

Permissions for your destination bucket

- `s3:PutObject`
- `s3:PutObjectAcl`
- `s3:PutObjectTagging`

Permissions for your source bucket

- `s3:GetObject`

Permissions for your manifest bucket

- `s3:GetObject`
- `s3:GetObjectVersion`
- `s3:GetBucketLocation`

Permissions for your report bucket

- `s3:PutObject`
- `s3:GetBucketLocation`

Here is a template that you can use

```js
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectTagging"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{{DestinationBucket}}/*"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{{SourceBucket}}/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::{{ManifestBucket}}/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action":[
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource":[
        "arn:aws:s3:::{{ReportBucket}}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can check [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/batch-ops-iam-role-policies.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I believe that it is correct as to the permissions required to run a batch job, but my issue is with job creation. The create_job method of the s3control client doesn't execute the job unless require confirmation is set to False. I believe that the error I am getting is in job creation, as I still get it even when require confirmation is True. Also not that there are two sets of permissions at play here - a user or role that creates the S3 job, and a role under which the S3 job executes.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer above does not answer the question, so I would certainly welcome other answers.